# MongoDB - Removing a single field in an embedded document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
    {
    "_id": "32dkd9020dl",
    "isTrue": true,
    "CategoriesAgentOf": [
       "Field1",
       "Field2",
       "Field3",
     ],
}
```

If I want to remove Field2, how can I do that? If each field had a value like "Field2": value, it would be easy, but this way seems impossible. Here is what I'm attempting:

```
removeField(email, field2){

    return Meteor.users.update({'emails.address': email}, {
      $pull: {
        "CategoriesAgentOf": {

          field2 
        }
      }

    })

  },
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was originally defining the field like this:

```
Meteor.users.update({"emails.address": (email)},{$push :{"CategoriesAgentOf": 
      category
    }});
```

I had to add brackets around category like such:

```
Meteor.users.update({"emails.address": (email)},{$push :{"CategoriesAgentOf": {
      category
    }}});
```

And changed my pull command to this:

```
$pull: {
        'CategoriesAgentOf': {

          category:
            cat

        }
      }
```